# retain original excel clipboard history after execution of vba macro

Tags: excel, clipboard, vba

**background information**

I use a VBA macro to execute a sequence of several single steps in order to exchange the contents of two rows within my sheet. In effect, I am thus able to move the selected row upwards row by row and so change its row order relative to the other rows. To execute this macro, I set a keyboard shortcut (or a button):

---

```
Sub MoveOneRowUp()

    Dim rowCurrent As Integer
    Dim colCurrent As Integer

    ' save current row coordinates
    rowCurrent = ActiveCell.Row
    colCurrent = ActiveCell.Column

    ' check validity
    If rowCurrent > 1 Then

        ' select row above active cell
        Rows(rowCurrent - 1).Select

        ' cut out entire row
        Selection.Cut

        ' select
        Rows(rowCurrent + 1).Select

        ' do the shift
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        ' select previously current cell
        Cells(rowCurrent - 1, colCurrent).Select

    End If

End Sub
```

---

The macro obviously modifies the clipboard because of selecting, cutting and inserting cell contents. Now, I would expect the clipboard history to stay intact after the macro execution. Thus enabling the user to reverse / cancel / withdraw what the macro has done and even go further back in global clipboard history. On my Windows system, I normally do this by pressing `<CTRL> + <Z>` . But after macro execution, all the clipboard history is gone and I can't reverse anything anymore.

**question**

What could I do in the described case to preserve the clipboard history regardless of macro executions? Is there some hint about how the clipboard history mechanism of EXCEL generally works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard could contain allsorts of complicated things so a reliable method of saving any contents would be at best difficult.  I believe you should avoid attempting that approach until you are convinced no other approach will given you what you want

A problem with trying to run a macro without changing the clipboard is that Excel clears the clipboard without you copying anything.  I do not know if Excel uses the clipboard itself or if it automatically clears the clipboard if you perform certain actions.

I tried a macro which copied row(current – 1) to a spare row, copied row(current) to row(current – 1), copied the spare row to row(current) and then cleared the spare row.  This moved the current row up one as you require but cleared the clipboard.

The macro below copies the two rows to variables then copies the values back reversed.  According tp my tests this does not clear the clipboard.  This macro does not copy any formatting but if all rows are formatted the same, this may be adequate.

```
 Sub MoveOneRowUp()

  ' Integer specifies a 16-bit variable which requires special (=slow) processing
  ' on 32 and 64-bit computers.  Perhaps more importantly, the maximum value that
  ' can be held in an integer variable is 32767 so make sure your worksheets
  ' don't have too many rows.
  Dim rowCurrent As Long
  Dim colCurrent As Long
  Dim rowContents1 As Variant
  Dim rowContents2 As Variant

  ' save current row coordinates
  rowCurrent = ActiveCell.Row
  colCurrent = ActiveCell.Column

  ' check validity
  If rowCurrent > 1 Then

    ' Copy row contents to variants then copy back reversed
    rowContents1 = Rows(rowCurrent - 1).Value
    rowContents2 = Rows(rowCurrent).Value
    Rows(rowCurrent).Value = rowContents1
    Rows(rowCurrent - 1).Value = rowContents2

    ' select previously current cell
    Cells(rowCurrent - 1, colCurrent).Select

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: copying values from/to variables helps in this case only if there are no links or formula to be moved around. Unfortunately, there is formula and link content which is to be retained while moving rows. Is there not a more general way to handle clipboard history? Like having a **clipboard object** which could be pushed into a temporary memory location before macro operation and pulled from there after operation?

Comment: @nnako. If you include a reference to Microsoft Forms n.n Object Library you have access to MSForms.DataObject which allows you to read/write text to the clipboard.  References: [DataObject Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264345.aspx) and  [Using The Clipboard In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx) .  If want to save more than text and if you know any of the .Net languages you could consider coding an Addin to get access to .Net's DataObject [DataObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

These subs will allow you to use the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>Z</kbd>** (Undo) and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>Y</kbd>** (Redo) shortcuts:

.

```
Public Sub MoveOneRowUp()
   Dim thisRow As Long

   thisRow = ActiveCell.Row

   With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If thisRow > 2 And thisRow < .Rows.Count + 1 Then  'check upper & lower bounds
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

         'insert new row
         .Rows(thisRow - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
         .Rows(thisRow - 1).Value2 = .Rows(thisRow + 1).Value2    'copy data
         .Rows(thisRow + 1).EntireRow.Delete                      'remove initial row

         .Cells(thisRow - 1, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
         Application.OnRepeat "Move One Row Up", "MoveOneRowUp"   'updates Repeat action
         Application.OnUndo "Move One Row Down", "MoveOneRowDown" 'updates Undo action
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub MoveOneRowDown()
   Dim thisRow As Long

   thisRow = ActiveCell.Row

   With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If thisRow > 1 And thisRow < .Rows.Count Then      'check upper & lower bounds
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False

         'insert new row
         .Rows(thisRow + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
         .Rows(thisRow + 2).Value2 = .Rows(thisRow + 0).Value2    'copy data
         .Rows(thisRow + 0).EntireRow.Delete                      'remove initial row

         .Cells(thisRow + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
         Application.OnRepeat "Move One Row Up", "MoveOneRowUp"   'updates Repeat action
         Application.OnUndo "Move One Row Down", "MoveOneRowDown" 'updates Undo action
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Details at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195810(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: your suggestion helps undoing the single operation of moving up (or down) a row within a sheet. Even though the single macro operation can be undone like this, the question remains how to undo the operations further back in the clipboard history after one of these macros was executed. Would your 2nd suggestion keep the old clipboard history of the backup sheet?

Comment: In Windows there is no clipboard history: open Notepad, type "1, 2, 3", copy "1" to clipboard, then copy "3" to clipboard - when you paste you'll get "3", and there is no way to paste the initially copied "1" anymore other than copying it again but if you do that, the last value in the clipboard ("3") will be replaced by the new value "1". In Excel, the Undo history is completely erased the moment you start executing VBA code - after you execute one macro there Undo history is cleared.

Comment: maybe the term "clipboard history" was mistaken by me. Sorry for that. I mean the simpler mechanism of an "undo history". Just so that users can go back and cancel their inputs e.g. until their last save operation. Currently I haven't managed to retain the "undo history" after execution of macros. The only way imaginable was to avoid certain macro operations and restrict cell contents to values / text (see the above solution of @TonyDallimore).

Comment: @nnako.  Excel maintains an Undo History and with Ctrl+Z the user can backtrack many steps.  Use of a VBA macro clears the Excel Undo History and no UnDo History is maintained of the macro's actions.  Do you want to (1) create a VBA Undo History and (2) not lose the Excel VBA History when a macro is executed?  That does not some simple to me.

Comment: @nnako. This discussion (which I found by searching for "Excel Undo History") might be of interest: [Capture undo history before event in excel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ef5ac45-9c62-4f17-a074-e9e8326941b0/capture-undo-history-before-event-in-excel)